# (Haskell) Parse error in pattern after Currying

Tags: haskell, currying, parse-error

I am getting a parse error after I changed this:

```
h :: ([Int],Int,[Int])->[[Int]]

h ([],k,x) =[[]]

h(y:[],k,x) = [x++k:[y]]

h(y:xs,k,x)= [x++k:y:xs]++h(xs,k,x++[y])
```

to this: at line 3

```
h :: [Int]->Int->[Int]->[[Int]]

h [] k x  =[[]]

h (y:[]) k x = [x++k:[y]]

h y:xs k x = [x++k:y:xs]++h(xs,k,x++[y])
```

Comment: h (y:[]) k x = [x++k:[y]] this is where the interpreter says NO

Comment: Hey, can you fix your code layout a little bit? It's hard to understand what's going on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this line:

```
h y:xs k x = [x++k:y:xs]++h(xs,k,x++[y])
  ^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  (1)                     (2)
```

1. You need parens around this pattern - `(y:xs)`
2. Unlike in other languages like C, Java, C#, etc, in Haskell you don't use commas to separate parameters to functions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, please. I'd like to add that in the expression `h (y:[]) k x`, `(y:[])` is expected to be a tuple `([Int],Int,[Int])` by declaration of `h`. In `h y:xs k x` then `y` is expected to be such a tuple.